How to force update nextjs react component?
Versions

Next.js : 14.0.3
React : 18.0.2

// TestClientComponent.tsx
"use client";
import { IResident } from "@interface/resident.types";
import { getResidents } from "@models/resident.service";
import { SolidButton } from "mds/desktop";
import React, { use, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TestClientComponent = () => {
  const [, forceUpdate] = useState<number>(0);

  const limit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  const response = use(
    getResidents({
      offset: 0,
      limit: limit,
    })
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test Client Component</h1>
      {response.data.map((resident: IResident) => {
        return <div key={resident.id}>{resident.name}</div>;
      })}
      <div>
        <SolidButton
          $inline
          $size="full"
          type="button"
          onClick={() => forceUpdate((n) => n + 1)}
        >
          업데이트
        </SolidButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestClientComponent;

// Main.tsx

// ...
            <Suspense
              fallback={Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, index) => index).map(
                (_, index) => (
                  <Skeleton key={index} height="62px" spacing={4} />
                )
              )}
            >
              <TestClientComponent />
            </Suspense>
// ...


This is the code I'm currently using. When I click SolidButton to take advantage of Suspense, I have to re-render the component. For that, I'm using a setState called forceUpdate. Of course it works, but I don't think it's awesome. Is there a better way to force re-render the component whenever I want in this environment at the moment?
If there isn't, is the method I'm using right now correct?

I appreciate the well-written question, I could immediately understand the problem you are having.
In order to answer your question, I have to clarify that React's components re-render for only 4 possible reasons.

State changes.
Parent re-render (Unless memo is used) Read here.
Context changes: React will re-render every child that subscribes to context when any of the states in that context is changed.
Hooks changes.
Props change (Euh, Not really): We know that the parent component is the one responsible for changing props of the current component, and in order for that to happen, the parent itself has to re-render, which brings us back to reason number 2 on this list, regardless of the props of the current component.

So using this list of reasons, I think that you've taken the easiest way to achieve your goal, even if it looks "ugly", I can't see any better option from an optimization standpoint.
In a slightly enhanced style, your code would be like this:
export default function App() {
 const [, updateState] = React.useState();
 const forceUpdate = React.useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);

 return (
     <button onClick={forceUpdate}> 업데이트 </button>
 );
}


Also please notice that re-rendering is separated into 2 types, Shallow and Deep, I'd suggest reading this for more information and tips.
